Journey is not taking the most updated Details of Subscriber
Requirement - Journey should pick up the most recent details of the subscriber while the subscriber is in the Journey.
Workaround - I have created a DE with one field as SubscriberKey (relates to subscriberkey) and another field as FinanceId(Primarykey) . The same DE is used in attribute group where ContactKey is linked with Subscriberkey . Cardinality is one to one. Now I am using the same DE as JourneyEntry Source.
Problem - The DE initial had 2 records with same subscriber key but different Financed. Upon Journey Activation, emails were sent on the email address as per DE . After first email there is 15 mins wait activity. During this, I made changes in the email address of those 2 records along with changes in their name . Unfortunately, the second email is sent as per the earlier data and not the updated data.
Journey Setting - Reentry anytime
Run - Scheduled every hour
Any idea what am I missing here
